# Alternative to DataInputStream.readLine when dealing with binary data (so NOT BufferedReader)

Tags: java, inputstream

In some situations, there is the need to read binary data mixed with ASCII text from an InputStream. For example, when processing a HTTP response, we have the headers in ASCII text, and then we may have binary data.

I am using `DataInputStream.readLine` to read the lines of the header, and then `DataInputStream.read` inside a loop for reading the binary data. Nevertheless, using that deprecated method is annoying to me.

Is there any other `FilterInputStream` (NOT `Reader`, as I am not dealing with codifications) which allows to read lines?

Would you use another aproach?

Comment: What exactly is a "line" in a binary data input ?

Comment: I talk about a stream mixing binary data and ascii text. Anyhow, a line is delimited by \r\n